# Failing tests after upgrade to laravel 5.8 / PHPUnit 8

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

After Upgrading to laravel 5.8 / PHPUnit 8 I had several tests that started failing. For example the following test.

```php
public function testAdminCanPromoteUsers()
{
    // While using a admin account try to promote non-admin user
    $this->actingAs($this->admin)
        ->post('user/promote', ['userPromoteId' => $this->user->id, 'name' => $this->user->name]);

    // check if user was promoted to admin
    $user = User::find($this->user->id);
    $this->assertTrue((bool) $user->isAdmin);
}
```

Routes

```
| POST     | user/allow    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@allow    | web,admin|
| POST     | user/demote   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@demote   | web,admin|
| POST     | user/promote  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@promote  | web,admin|
| POST     | user/reset    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@reset    | web,admin|
| POST     | user/restrict | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@restrict | web,admin|
```

user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

}
```

user migration

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email', 191)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('hasAccess')->default(true);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

UserController function

```
    /**
    * Make an user as admin
    */
    public function promote(Request $request) {
        // Create the collection name
        $thisUsr = User::findOrFail($request->userPromoteId);
        if (strcasecmp($thisUsr->name, $request->name) == 0) {
          $thisUsr->isAdmin = true;
          $thisUsr->save();
          return redirect()->route('userIndex');
        }

        // Error message
        return redirect()->route('userIndex')->withErrors("Failed to Promote User to Admin. User wasn't found.");
    }
```

PHPUnit Results

> 1) UserControllerTest::testAdminCanPromoteUsers
>   Failed asserting that false is true.
>
> /var/www/tests/Feature/Controllers/UserControllerTest.php:61

Everything still is working in the browser just the test is failing. Any ideas on what may have changed that would cause this to fail.

Comment: Can you post the whole User model please?

Comment: done updated the question.

Comment: Is `$user->isAdmin` a field? Is `$this->user` persisted to the db in the tests?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: What kind of field is `isAdmin`?

Comment: added migration to question it is boolean but when looking at the database it comes up as tinyint(1)

Comment: Can you verify that  `$user` is not null in this line? `$user = User::find($this->user->id);`

Comment: I checked it is correct. it is set in setUp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people suggest adding `$this->withoutMiddleware();` to the function, but that hasn't worked well for me. Try running it with a token present.

```
$this->actingAs($this->admin)
        ->post('user/promote', ['userPromoteId' => $this->user->id, 'name' => $this->user->name, '_token' => csrf_token()]);
```

Comment: Gage adding the token didn't have any effect. But adding the withoutMiddleware() allowed the test to pass.